# Restful API: implement version handling

Tags: asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have deference version of API in the same domain and i want manage it by putting version number in url like below

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/user/getall
mydomain.com/api/v1/user/add

mydomain.com/api/v2/user/getall
mydomain.com/api/v2/user/add
```

imagine this scenario:
get user in both version has same functionality but add changed in V2.
Now i wanna implement versioning, i found tow approach for this aim.

1. use V1 and V2 in routing and manage versioning in application (u.e : [SDammann WebApi Versioning](https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning) )
2. Manage versioning by source controllers and web servers ( for each version exists a branch and in case of ASP.net(IIS) create sub-application for each version)

In first approach i think we have to copy controller s and action, so if found a bug for example in get user action we must change it in both action (**redundancy**)

in second approach if happened some bug we must checkout to old branch, fix it and merge it by new version branch.

Dose exists any better approach for manage and implementation of API versioning ?

Comment: Yes, use URL routing within the same WebAPI to map the request to the right controller version.

Comment: @Chris but in this approach, if happens problem for application, all version go out of work! is it ok? 
i really confused for finding best approach

Comment: you haven't specified any DR requirements. If you are looking on serving different content based on a version number then routing is the cleanest way. If you are looking into DR scenarios, then that's a different question all together. Also, keeping separate branches for each version means that you will have two streams to maintain, which is not advisable.

Comment: @Chris Ok, But what about code redundancy in same functionality in deference version of api? do you have any solution?

Comment: If the method is not different then what's the point of moving it to v2? What's different between v1 and v2 other than the number? Going by the DRY approach, you should never repeat the same code so you need to rethink your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Branching for different service versions could lead to a *deployment nightmare*, because you would need to maintain/test/deploy a lot of separate applications at the same time. So, idea with a *single* application and proper routing system in it looks more promising for me. BUT, you need to guarantee that you don't have shared code pathways, otherwise you could introduce new problems in one version working with another. What about duplicating? I believe that it is inevitable at some degree anyway, if you want to separate your versions on the code level to guarantee safe modifications. Some professionals even [think](http://nimbleunion.wordpress.com/tag/martin-fowler/) that you don't need to perform bug-fixing in old versions: any bug-fix just introduces new service version.